# Fedora 24 logind and accountd service failed to start

Tags: linux, boot, fedora, fedora-24

Yesterday while I was installing updates on Fedora 24 I powered off my machine by mistake. When I restarted, I got the error message

> ```
> Failed to start logind.service
> Failed to start accountd.service
> ```

and few other services and the login prompt/GUI never got loaded.

I tried to login in single user mode and when I ran

```
systemctl status systemd-logind.service
```

the message pointed that it has not loaded the service

When I ran `journalctl systemd-logind.service` no entries printed out.

startx or even systemctl start systemd-logind.service or accountd.service, none of these commands are working.

I could not power off as the shutdown command was also not found.

Any pointers to recover the system is much appreciated.

Comment: When the system first starts, there should be a GRUB menu for a second. That should include a "rescue mode" option. Does that work?

Comment: Oh, I see that you can get to single-user mode. From there, can activate a network connection?

Comment: Nopes. I could not. I tried to look up the network. I got only as far as seeing my wirless harware and drivers. When I assign it to my network or try to search for available networks. No result. Finally after 2 days I gave up and re installed my OS. Lost all data, but fortunately had backed up some of it!

Comment: Did you try the rescue mode?

Answer (score 0):

Well, After two days of frustration and sleepless nights, I re-installed my OS.

I am sure there should be a better way. Because system getting hung during installation must be a common problem. If anybody knows the answer, please post.

For now, My answer is re install the OS.